# FusionChart draw data points

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I want to draw just data points. I mean that i do not want to draw a line. I just want to show data points in fusion chart graph. I tried some possible options however it was not successful. This is the link that i want to do: [fusionchart bubble](http://www.fusioncharts.com/explore/bubble-xy-charts/)

I tried first example's xml file . However it shows nothing. This is the renderchart code that i used:

```
 FCLiteral1.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("FusionCharts/FCF_MSLine.swf", "",
        strXML,
        "mygraph4",
        GraphWidth, GraphHeight,
        False
        )
```

This is in asp.net. Is there anybody who knows how to display data points using fusion chart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionCharts Free does not support Bubble chart. To meet your requirement using FusionCharts Free, to show only data points `<dataset alpha='0' showAnchors='1'>`

Refer to the supported XML format for MSLine.swf at [Link](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/free/Contents/ChartSS/XML_MSLine2D.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first argument of your function to `FusionCharts/Bubble.swf` assuming `strXML` has the right data structure for a bubble chart.

Comment: Yes i can share value of strXml. Link is : [point.xml](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/578408/point-xml.html) By the way, i have no bubble.swf :S

Comment: The xml you have shared is invalid xml, there should be space between seriesname and color attribute and space between x and y attributes. Also instead of x:1000, it should be x = "1000".